# VS Code - Internal terminal is gone

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

My VS Code internal terminal is gone.
Clicking `>Terminal - New Terminal` does not work and nothing happens at all.

Opening the bottom bar the terminal tab is there but clicking that tab shows a completely blank window. No indication of being type at all there. There simply is no terminal under the terminal tab at all.

I have tired a complete fresh install of VS Code and deleted all local settings. My `Settings.json` is completely empty `{}`.
Clicking `Select Default Profile` also does nothing. I also have no errors in for VS Code.

[image]

I simply can't find a solution to this problem. I been googling around for hours now but can't seem to find anyone with this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently restarting my PC fixed the issue.